# Squish this Android NDK File Access Bug

Tags: android, c++, file, android-ndk

I cannot figure out why this solution will let me open and modify files bytes with ofstream/ifstream, but reads/writes will not update the pointer accessed through tellp / tellg function calls.

This is a sample that does not work:

```
std::ofstream oStream(path,std::fstream::beg | std::fstream::binary);
int test = 98;
LOGI("OSTREAM POINTf :: %d", oStream.tellp());
oStream.write((char *)&test,4);
LOGI("OSTREAM POINT :: %d", oStream.tellp());
oStream.close();
oStream.clear();
```

In Both cases, the above Log's: 0

It cannot be said that it is not writing to the files. Because I can easily write and read any bytes I want. The problem is that, it can only read/write bytes @ the beginning of the file.

This permission is provided to my manifest, and I have ensured it is permitted on the device itself.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: `std::fstream::beg` is not valid for the constructor of `std::ofstream` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode and  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream

Comment: I removed it from the solution, but still i beg... I cannot get the stream pointer to lift. I think it will have to create a new file every time it writes something new. Which completely smashes my optimization attempt. aha Thanks for the input.

Comment: I restructured my code, and now I am able to lift the stream pointer. But I can only do so via reads and writes; seek? does not work.